# paste parts of picture - python, PIL module

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, paste

I want to split two pictures (pic A and pic B - both same size) to Up and Down Halfs (A-Up,A-Down,B-Up,B-Down), and then create new images: A-up + B-Down and vise versa (meaning: I want to have a new picture that its upper half is in fact the upper of A and the down half is of B). I wrote the next function in python, using PIL module:

```
import Image  
def SplitFunction(BMP):  
      im = Image.open(BMP)  
      [x,y]=im.size  
      box1=(0,0,x,y/2)  
      box2=(0,y/2+1,x,y)  
      region1 = im.crop(box1)    
      region2 = im.crop(box2)  
      region1.show()  
      region2.show()  
      return [region1,region2]  

path1='c:/movie2frames/BMPs1/stim/1.BMP'  
path2='c:/movie2frames/BMPs1/stim/334.BMP'  

[r1a,r2a]=SplitFunction(path1)  
[r1b,r2b]=SplitFunction(path2)  
#end program
```

I don't know how to paste the new parts. Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually much easier if you keep the original full-size image and paste a new top half into it.

```
box_top = (0, 0, x, y / 2)
top_part = im1.crop(box_top)
result = im2.copy()
result.paste(top_part, box_top)
```

Comment: thanks. I understand the logic (and it is ofcourse much easier) but for some reason I get an error on the paste command that the images do not match [thogh they are the same size originally]. of course I added im2.open(...). any ideas?

Comment: @user552231, make sure they're the same mode. Use the `convert` function to convert to `'RGB'` mode if necessary.

Comment: thank you. but this does not seem to be the problem. I guess I am on my own with this bug.. I am attaching the new function [but I guess it is not really readble:import Image
def SplitFunction(BMP1,BMP2):
     im1 = Image.open(BMP1)
     im2 = Image.open(BMP2)
     [x,y]=im1.size
     box_top = (0, 0, x, y / 2 )
     top_part = im1.crop(box_top)
     result = im2.copy()
     result.paste(im1, box_top)

     return result

path1='c:/movie2frames/BMPs1/stim/1.BMP'
path2='c:/movie2frames/BMPs1/stim/334.BMP'
SplitFunction(path1,path2)

Comment: @user552231, my mistake - it should be `result.paste(top_part, box_top)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new image of the size of the both parts:

```
im = Image.new(mode, size)
```

Then paste the separated images:

```
im.paste(image, box)
```

For more details see documentation: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm